# As she grew older she gained in confidence. (parts of speech of 'in')

Tags: parts-of-speech

> As she grew older she gained **in** confidence.

Is the 'in' a preposition or an adverb?

Can the sentence be rephrased as 'she gained confidence in'?

Comment: It's a rather "dated, literary" usage. Most people in most contexts today wouldn't actually include the preposition "in" here. In principle, including "in" *very slightly* implies she already had *some* confidence even when she was younger (she gained ***more*** confidence). But mostly it's just "starchy" phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

In that sentence, "in" is a preposition, and "confidence" is its object, so the sentence cannot be reworded the way you've suggested.

"Gain" can be a transitive or intransitive verb. When it's intransitive, it doesn't mean "acquire", but roughly means "improve" or "have an increase". We can indicate by what metric it improves or increases with a prepositional phrase with "in". This phrase has similar meaning to "in terms of...".

> This pill will likely cause your cat to gain in both alertness and energy.

We can see here it's a different meaning from the transitive "gain" because the pill doesn't cause the cat to directly gain alertness or energy, but the result is an overall increase in both.

So in your original sentence, "gain" is intransitive, and the prepositional phrase "in confidence" means that the quantity that increased is confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Well.....
Yes, but it is **unusual**.

As she grew older she gained in confidence.

would probably be more like this:

As she grew older *she became more confident*.

*in confidence* in English has a different meaning:

"May I tell you something *in confidence*?" [privately, between  us]

in confidence is a noun phrase used adverbially.

"in" is always a preposition. Even in phrasal verbs like take in (take in a lodger, for example).

Comment: Do you mean "yes" that "in" is a preposition or that it can be paraphrased "she gained confidence in"?

Comment: @gotube I think my answer is pretty clear.

Comment: Reading your answer, I'm not clear what "yes" means until your last sentence. Also, "in" isn't always a preposition. It can be an adjective, adverb and noun too.

Answer (score -1):

With the verbs 'lose' or 'gain', and their synonyms, 'in' is a noise word. It serves no purpose whatsoever. (Like 'up' when used with 'park', 'manage' and a lot of other verbs.)

You can say *"As she grew older she gained confidence."*, and it means exactly the same thing.

It's confusing for learners, because its function in *"said in confidence"*, or *"told in confidence"* is entirely different. Here there are a lot of 'understood' words. Its full equivalent would be: *"said in the confidence that it will not be repeated"*.

Comment: Your rephrasing is identical to the original. Can you give a reference that explains what a "noise word" is? Did you mean "function word", or is this something different? How can "up" be used with "park" or "manage"?

Comment: @Lambie I find that part idiomatic.

Comment: @gotube This is not idiomatic: "[somebody] said in the confidence that it will not be repeated".

Comment: @Lambie I parse it like a passive: "*(It was) said in the confidence that it will not be repeated*"

Comment: @gotube "said in the confidence" is just not good English. Said in confidence that it would not be repeated.